# convert Left half of RGB image into Grayscale (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I need a Matlab code to convert left half of my RGB image into grayscale and leave right Half as it is ?
I already know how to convert whole image to grayscale using "rgb2gray" command, but I want to convert only left or Right half to gray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since images in Matlab can in essence be regarded just as (pixel) matrices (with RGB having 3 depth layers as compared to the single depth layer of grayscale), you could just treat them as such, in which case constructing a split image reduces to some simple operations on matrices:

- compute the grayscale matrix of your image,
- and construct a new matrix (i.e. your split image) where the left half make use the grayscale image for all 3 layers, whereas the right half make use the 3 RGB layers.

E.g.

```
imgRGB = imread('peppers.png');
imgGray = rgb2gray(imgRGB);

[r, c, ~] = size(imgRGB);
c = round(c/2);

imgSplit = imgRGB;
for i = 1:3
  imgSplit([1:r],[1:c],i) = imgGray([1:r],[1:c]);
end

imshow(imgSplit)
%// imwrite(imgSplit,'imgSplit.png')
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you don't want space overhead for two new image matrices (`imgGray` and `imgRGB`) you can mutate the rgb image matrix directly, yielding the same result as the above.

```
imgRGB = imread('peppers.png');

[r, c, ~] = size(imgRGB);
c = round(c/2);

imgRGB([1:r],[1:c],1) = rgb2gray(imgRGB([1:r],[1:c],:)); 
for i = 2:3
  imgRGB([1:r],[1:c],i) = imgRGB([1:r],[1:c],1);
end

imshow(imgRGB)
%// imwrite(imgRGB,'imgSplit.png')
```

Comment: One line version: `img(:, 1:end/2, :) = repmat(rgb2gray(img(:, 1:end/2, :)), 1, 1, 3);`

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro Thanks; your condensed version of the above is a good addition, especially if brevity is of importance for OP using this in practice.

Comment: Thanks both of you guys, much appreciated your answers.  Can we have detailed conversation on matlab codes somewhere else ? @Rafael Monteiro, and dfri.